# React-Devtools discontinued or just moved? (React Native debugging)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging, github, react-devtools

I started with React Native today and I downloaded `react-devtools` from npm repo to debug Components hiearchy of React Native Expo app. It works fine, but it crashing sometimes.

Thats why I tried to search for some new version or something and I found, that GitHub repo of this project no longer exists (https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) and was moved to (https://github.com/facebook/react). I dont understand where I can now found this tool in main React repo? Or project is discontinued? Are there some equivalents? Am I using some Legacy version?

Even debugged in browser (http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui/) telling me to download this app from non-existing repo.

Comment: Why don't you ask the authors? Sorry, but that's not really a programming question.

Comment: Who else should know? Just programmers and authors. Authors are not really easy to contact...

Answer (score 0):

> Are there some equivalents?

I have been using [reactotron](http://%20https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron) for the need of `devtools`. This tool has way more options than devtools and the guide to install can be found here

https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/blob/master/docs/quick-start-react-native.md